# How can I get my DIV to appear below another DIV

Tags: html, css

I have this situation:

```
<div A>
  <div B>
  <div C>
```

Div A is a full screen width container for B and C. 
Div B is a small rectangle say 100 by 200 px
Div C is another small rectangle say 100 by 200 px.

Now what happens is that B and C appear on the same line. What I would like is for C to be below B. Is it possible to position Div's in this way. I hope I make sense.

Comment: We need to see your CSS, and ideally the real HTML involved(in case something's broken there). Divs are block elements by default, and C already *should* be appearing under B. Something, probably in the CSS, is causing it not to.

Comment: Hello, They are appearing like blocks. The problem the Block C follows Block B on the same line. I guess it does this because there is space. My question is how can I get it to go below B?

Comment: My point isn't about whether they *look* like blocks. I mean that they're [block elements](http://css.flepstudio.org/en/css-tips/inline-block-elements.html) and as such should already be doing what you want. From your description, they're behaving like inline elements(or like they're floated) and that only happens if you *tell* them to do it. Which is why we need your CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that they're floated to the left already or they wouldn't be beside each other. A simple `clear: left` on C will do the trick:

```
#B {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #0f0;
    margin: 5px;
}
#C {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #00f;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

I've added some margins, paddings, and backgrounds for clarity.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/uCBYV/

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="1"> container
   <div id="2"> first in
   </div>
   <div id="3"> second in
   </div>
</div>
```

And then the css, to add some style:

```
div
{
 border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;  
}
```

See it in live here: http://jsfiddle.net/CaN87/

The third div goes directly on bottom of the second, and so I believe you are having some troubles in your CSS code...

Answer (score 0):

By default C should be below B. Can you post some html and the styles being applied to the divs ? It looks like something changes their display to 'inline' or that they are floating.